# Need regex for removing <select> and <option> html tag

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am parsing an html file in C# and extracting the text from html. My html file has a lot of tags in it. Html file has select tag and option tag. I need a regex for removing the select tag and option tag from html file. I don't want this information. So I want to delete it using any regex.

Below is the html that I want to remove from my html file:

```
 <select name="state" onchange="setCities();" id="state">>

 <option value="CA" selected="selected">CA</option>
 <option value="WA">WA</option>
 <option value="TX">TX</option>
 <option value="NV">NV</option>
 <option value="CO">CO</option>
 <option value="MI">MI</option>
 <option value="SC">SC</option>
```

Comment: You DO NOT need regex for parsing HTML.

Comment: Just for fun: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Why so complicated? myHTMLString.Replace("<option>", string.Empty);

Comment: Get this; http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have tried so far this regex Regex.Replace(input, @"<select(\s+[^>]*)?>(<option(\s+[^>]*)?>.*?</option(\s+[^>]*)?>)*</select(\s+[^>]*)?>", string.Empty);

Comment: @Amar Palsapure,I have to remove these html tags from my html file,I do not need this informaion.I need regex for removing <select > and <option> tag from my html file.Thanks

Comment: I have done it myself, this is the regex that I have used @"<select(\s+[^>]*)?>(.|\n)*?</select(\s+[^>]*)?>".Thanks to my mighty Allah.Also thanks to who give me feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use RegEx to simply strip the HTML tags.
The following method iterates through the HTML code string and creates a new return string without any tags.
This way is faster than RegEx too.

```
public static string StripHTMLTags(string str)
    {
        char[] array = new char[str.Length];
        int arrayIndex = 0;
        bool inside = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = str[i];
            if (c == '<')
            {
                inside = true;
                continue;
            }
            if (c == '>')
            {
                inside = false;
                continue;
            }
            if (!inside)
            {
                array[arrayIndex] = c;
                arrayIndex++;
            }
        }
        return new string(array, 0, arrayIndex);
    }
```

Comment: This will fail if you have `>` inside HTML comment. And the question is not about removing *all* tags, only some specific ones.

Comment: @QQping,@Svick,I have done it myself, this is the regex that I have used @"<select(\s+[^>]*)?>(.|\n)*?</select(\s+[^>]*)?>".Thanks to my mighty Allah.Also thanks to who give me feedback.